# c# SerialPort how to force ignore parity errors?

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I'm connecting with a 485 serial port device, the device uses **Even** parity, but perhaps its parity signal isn't strong or reliable enough and sometimes can't pass c# SerialPort check, thus padding some received bytes with '?' characters.

1. I tried different serial port debuggers, some can receive all data right, and some can't just like the c# program does. So there should be some way to ignore parity errors and just read the data, but how?
2. I searched and found c++ has a flag to ignore parity error, but our whole program is in c#, we have not that enough time to reprogram.
3. I tried to set the parity property to **None**, and manually convert the received bytes to bits, and using bit operators to discard every 9th bit and reconstruct the other bits to bytes. However it doesn't work either. I try to find the reason, and perhaps it's because serial port bit flow is not continuous and contains something like stop bits itself, so I can't just reinterpret the bits?
4. Or if there exists some third party c# serial port library, able to ignore parity error?

Comment: What exactly is the error you're seeing? Is the data your receive supposed to be ASCII or could it just be that you receive binary data which cannot be printed?

Comment: If the device that will have access uses even parity then you must use the same even parity in your program.

RS485 communication uses half duplex, meaning that sending and receiving cannot be done simultaneously (they must take turns).

You should add a delay (100-200ms) to the RS485 flow control to ensure the data reaches its destination, before you change the flow control to receive mode.

Comment: Vote to close. This is obviously an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). The typical cause of (random/occasional) parity errors is EMI; but RS-485 uses a differential pair to minimize that problem. The occurrence of persistent parity errors would probably indicate some other underlying issue that should not be ignored.

Comment: Maybe the real problem is on the device side, but we can't change the device. We asked the device producer, they just said "ah, that debugger(with ignore) works, so the device is ok." So the only thing we can do is to ignore the errors ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is a simple solution, I'm stupid didn't find it previously.

`SerialPort sp; sp.Parity = Parity.Even; sp.ParityReplace = 0;` 
Set ParityReplace to zero and it's all ok. The zero means don't replace parity-error bytes.